# Android emulator running Lollipop even when I tell it to run Gingerbread?

Tags: android, emulation, android-2.3-gingerbread

I have the following setup in my AVDs on Mac OS/X Yosemite:

[image: Android AVDs]

As you can see, I've installed the SDK for Gingerbread (2.3.3), API v10 and am using it in the first two AVDs. However, when I go to run one of these two AVDs, I get the following:

[image: Actual AVD Running]

As you can see, the image appears to be running Lollipop, based on the virtual buttons at the bottom, the system settings `Android Version`, and even my own testing in my app by printing out `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT`. Moreover, the AVD description at the top of the window shows that I *should* be running API v10.

How can I get it to *actually* run API v10? I'd like to debug an issue that the app is apparently having in API v10 only.

**UPDATE:**

Interestingly, if I create an AVD designed to run KitKat 4.4.2 (API 19), the AVD manager creates and launches the correct image.

Comment: That's wild. You could go to `~/.android/avd/.../` (where ... is the name of an AVD) and look at `config.ini` to see what `image.sysdir.1` points to. On my 2.3.3 API Level 10 AVD, it points to `system-images/android-10/x86/` (in my case, I'm using the x86 emulator).

Comment: Interesting.. yeah, on my machine it points to: `image.sysdir.1=system-images/android-21/google_apis/armeabi-v7a/` which is clearly the 5.0 SDK. This must be a bug in the AVD manager, then, because that's how I set it up.

Comment: Also interesting - I don't have a `system-images/android-10/armeabi-xxx` directory. So I wonder if this is where it got confused. I only have `system-images/android-10/default/x86`

Comment: Editing this option, though, and then trying to launch the emulator just causes it to crash. :(

Comment: There may be other settings elsewhere in the AVD configuration to be able to switch architectures. Perhaps you did not download the ARM emulator image for API Level 10.

Comment: Hmm.. the sdk manager doesn't seem to give me an option for the ARM emulator image for android-10. It only has the x86 version.

Comment: It would be in the "SDK Platform" entry. The ARM emulators were only broken out separately starting with API Level 14 (Android 4.0).

Comment: Ah, ok. Yeah, the following packages are installed under Android 2.3.3 (API 10): `SDK Platform`, `Samples for SDK`, `Intel x86 Atom System Image`, and `Google APIs`.